# In wordpress and in theme storefront I want to show search box for shop page only.how can I do it

Tags: wordpress

is_shop is not working in function.php  file so where i put conditinal tag.In function.php is_shop give false ,so how to determine page for shop  .I want to show search box in shop page and cart page only .Thanks in advance

Comment: In the templates that generate the output …?

Comment: please elaborate your answer

Comment: What’s there to elaborate? You want to output something under specific conditions only, and output usually happens inside the template files ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39721610/wordpress-how-to-create-a-custom-search-form-only-to-a-specific-page

Comment: so I have to put   if(is_shop) { } in header to show search box in shop page only